# Flot - combine Bar and stacked chart in a sigle chart

Tags: javascript, charts, flot

Is it possible to combine Bar chart and stacked chart in flot? 
I did line with bar.

Bar chart will have 4 legends. 5th bar will be stacked.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which stack plugin you use this is different but should be possible in all of them, since the option for stacking is usually specified per dataseries.